# NSTask pipes output to Console rather than the NSFileHandle

Tags: java, objective-c, nstask, nsfilehandle

I set up an NSNotification for `NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification`.

I set up the standard I/O with two separate pipes.

```
NSPipe * input  = NSPipe.new;
NSPipe * output = NSPipe.new;

[serverTask setStandardInput:input];
[serverTask setStandardOutput:output];
```

I launch a NSTask executing a Java jar, and start reading the data.

`[[serverTask.standardOutput fileHandleForReading] readInBackgroundAndNotify];`

and I continuously read the data and append the data in an `NSTextView` if it is new data:

```
- (void)serverLogHasChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[serverTask.standardOutput fileHandleForReading] readInBackgroundAndNotify];

    NSData * newData = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];

    if (newData != nil && availableData != newData)
    {
        NSMutableString * serverLogString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:serverLog.string];

        [serverLogString appendString:[NSString.alloc initWithData:newData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [serverLog setString:serverLogString];
        [serverLog.enclosingScrollView.contentView scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(0, NSMaxY(serverLog.enclosingScrollView.contentView.bounds))];
    }

    newData = availableData;
}
```

However, I'm getting strange output into the `NSTextView`

[image]

Those ">" characters should be lines of actual output, but instead the output ends up in Xcode's console.

In other words, the console is printing out the output instead of my `NSPipe` which is printing out only the indication of new lines of the output.

Comment: Hmm, Mine Craft Wrapper? And did you try setting the output of the task to `[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput]`?

Comment: Yup. If I do that I get nothing in the NSTextView and now those characters in the console: `174 recipes
27 achievements
>
10:46:49 [INFO] Starting minecraft server version 1.1
>
10:46:49 [INFO] Loading properties
>
10:46:49 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on localhost:25565
>` etc...

Comment: Any chance the output you are trying to catch is going to standard error? If so you need to capture that as well.

Comment: Oh wow.. Thanks CRD, It makes zero sense but it was located under Standard Error. Thanks!

Comment: @CRD If you want to copy your answer in the comments to an actual answer post to this question you can get points and close the question..

Comment: evdude100, any chance you might share your NSTask arguments list? I'm having trouble launching a java session using NSTask that doesn't result in a broken VM.  More specifically, "Unrecognized option: -jar foo.jar"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been commented above, it's a case of adding catching the standard error output. I've had a similar issue recently. I solved it by doing the following:

```
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[javaTask setStandardOutput:pipe];
[javaTask setStandardError:pipe];
NSFileHandle *fileHandleForReading = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[javaTask launch];

NSData *result = [fileHandleForReading readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Thanks, CRD for your help.